# How do I get a long (more than 1 page) bibliography to print in an R markdown beamer?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer, bibliography

I have an issue rendering bibliographies covering more than one page as only the first one is printed using RMarkdown and beamer output.

The same question has been posted at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#comment-2398115545 but without any help.

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: beamer_presentation
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can force a slide to be continued on the next one by setting its class to `allowframebreaks`. Just do this for your last slide. From the pandoc [mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/42uPo1nBsQc/kZTZFdQuRz0J):

```
## References {.allowframebreaks}
```

Edit: `knitr` has a setting that prevents this solution from working out of the box with `rmarkdown`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677857/references-truncated-in-beamer-presentation-prepared-in-knitr-rmarkdown/35681531) for a solution.