# References Truncated in Beamer Presentation prepared in Knitr/RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I'm currently preparing a presentation in RStudio (using RMarkdown and Knitr, outputting to a Beamer presentation) that has quite a few references.

I'm using a pretty typical YAML header:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
date: "February 27th, 2016"
output: 
  beamer_presentation
csl: ../../apa.csl
bibliography: ../../RefenceDesk.bib 
---
```

This presentation compiles and the references appear as they should, but unfortunately they all appear on one slide (and actually run off the page).  Is there any way to have the references appear on multiple slides?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @David above said in the comments:

> For me it didnt work with ## References {.allowframebreaks} but it worked out with # References {.allowframebreaks}.

I would like to point out that, apparently for the reference slide to work you have to create a last slide with the same heading level es set by `slide_level: __` at the *YAML* section.

So, the user should set one of the following:

- # References {.allowframebreaks}. for those using `slide_level: 1`, OR
- ## References {.allowframebreaks}. for those using `slide_level: 2`, OR
- ### References {.allowframebreaks}. for those using `slide_level: 3` and so on...

Comment: It's {.allowframebreaks}  not {.allowframebrakes} if anyone is failing because of the spelling..

Comment: is it possible to set allowframebreaks for all slides (all levels) ?

Comment: yes, it is. just append the option {.allowframebreaks} after every slide title. (there might be a way to change in in the yaml options for all slides, but I am not aware of.

Answer (score 15):

`{.allowframebreaks}` is the solution for multislides bibliographies in beamer. It works out of the box with regular pandoc templates (see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158723/how-do-i-get-a-long-more-than-1-page-bibliography-to-print-in-an-r-markdown-be)). However, `knitr` has a setting that prevents it, by redefining `\widowpenalties` in its beamer template. You can verify that if you examine the `.tex` file with `keep_tex: true`.

In my opinion, this is a bug. A quick fix would be to reset `\widowpenalties` to its default value. It can be done in your yaml front matter:

```
---
title: Title
header-includes:
  - \widowpenalties 1 150
output: 
  beamer_presentation
---
```

Then, you can indicate the reference section as such:

```
## References {.allowframebreaks}
```

Comment: Interesting! I discovered `{.allowframebreaks}` last night, but it didn't do anything. I've just tried adding the header-includes - but it doesn't actually seem to change the values in the .tex file.  After I compile, if I open the .tex file, it still says `\widowpenalties 1 10000`.

Comment: For me it didnt work with `## References {.allowframebrakes}` but it worked out with `# References {.allowframebrakes}`.

Answer (score 3):

While this goes outside of using the regular pandoc citation template, I have found another approach that can be used to put the references across slides but it relies on the `natbib` citation package.

In the YAML front matter, I added:

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: ../../RefenceDesk.bib 
biblio-style: "apalike"
---
```

The reference slide does not get a title and I cannot seem to adjust the font size (by using a `\scriptsize` at the end of the `.Rmd` file), but at least they appear coherently.

EDIT: For parsimony, I removed the `csl: ../../apa.csl` line, since natbib does not require it.

Comment: Worked for me! If anyone gets a natbib-caused error `! LaTeX Error: \newblock undefined.` then just add this line `\newcommand{\newblock}{}`